# Entity Frame Work Migration error on Publish

Tags: c#, entity-framework

After the last changes I made to out software when I publish it the site crashes with a 500 error trying telling the context has changed.  It hasn't.  The application runs in VS2017, and the database it talks to is dev mode is the same one it talks to published live on the server.

I have tried adding this
Database.SetInitializer(null);
to my app start,

then it complains that one of my classes is missing.

What might I be missing

Here is the Exception message from the event viewer and stack trace

Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: The model backing the 'DMDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database  at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at Delta_Manager.Controllers.SettingsController.GetSettingByName(String name) in C:\prog\DeltaManager\Delta_Manager\Controllers\SettingsController.cs:line 79
   at Delta_Manager.Controllers.ApplicationContext.MakeOrResetInitialSetting() in C:\prog\DeltaManager\Delta_Manager\Controllers\ApplicationContext.cs:line 1238
   at Delta_Manager.Controllers.ApplicationContext.Initialize() in C:\prog\DeltaManager\Delta_Manager\Controllers\ApplicationContext.cs:line 177
   at Delta_Manager.WEB.Global.Application_AcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\prog\DeltaManager\Delta_Manager.WEB\Global.asax.cs:line 44
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

```
Stack trace:    at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
```

at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at Delta_Manager.Controllers.SettingsController.GetSettingByName(String name) in C:\prog\DeltaManager\Delta_Manager\Controllers\SettingsController.cs:line 79
   at Delta_Manager.Controllers.ApplicationContext.MakeOrResetInitialSetting() in C:\prog\DeltaManager\Delta_Manager\Controllers\ApplicationContext.cs:line 1238
   at Delta_Manager.Controllers.ApplicationContext.Initialize() in C:\prog\DeltaManager\Delta_Manager\Controllers\ApplicationContext.cs:line 177
   at Delta_Manager.WEB.Global.Application_AcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\prog\DeltaManager\Delta_Manager.WEB\Global.asax.cs:line 44
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: Doesn't the exception contain any information about what it thinks has changed?

Comment: Maybe your EF DBContext structure is not the same as your actual DB structure.

Comment: I created a new website on the same server, published the site there, and it works.  Could something be cached by IIS or in the registry for the other site?